# Does $(ab)^n=(ba)^n$ with $a^n=e$ imply $ab=ba$ in a group $G$?

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group and $a,b \in G$. Moreover, suppose $(ab)^n=(ba)^n=b$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Here $a^n=e$ but $a$ is not necessarily the identity element. Can we conclude $ab=ba$?

I know in general it is not true that $(ab)^n=(ba)^n \Rightarrow ab = ba$. But in this case, $a^n=e$, which might change the situation. I cannot make the conclusion that the implication is entailed.

Comment: How did you conclude that $a^n=e$?

Comment: If I understand correctly, $a^n=e$ is a given.

Comment: It is given that $a^n=e$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the reasoning:

$$(ab)^n=b$$
$$(ab)^na=ba$$
$$a(ba)^n=ba$$
$$ab=ba$$

> I know in general it is not true that $(ab)^n=(ba)^n \Rightarrow ab = ba$. But in this case, $a^n=e$, which might change the situation. I cannot make the conclusion that the implication is entailed.

Note that $a^n=e$ is irrelevant. What really matters is that not only $(ab)^n=(ba)^n$ but more importantly that both are equal to $b$.

Comment: why on the third line you have $a(ba)^n = ba$? I know $a(ba)^n = ab$

Comment: true, but then shouldn't $a(ba)^n=ab$ and not $ba$?

Comment: @Josh $(ab)^na=a(ba)^n$. I just move the brackets in the previous line. Each line is the previous line modified somehow.

Comment: Then how do we know $(ab)^na = a(ba)^n$?

Comment: @Josh by induction? Here's a hint: $(abab)a=a(baba)$. It is just bracket replacement.

Comment: Regarding the assumption $a^n = e$, its worth pointing out that it's not just unnecessary, but also does not follow from the other assumptions. In the group $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z},+)$, let $a = 3$, $b = 2$ and $n=2$. We have $2(3 + 2) = 2$ and $2(2 + 3) = 2$, but $3 + 3 = 2 \neq 0$.

Comment: I see now! I think this only makes sense because we are multiplying each side by the same element $a$.